# Using Class Type as Dictionary Key

Tags: swift, dictionary, strong-typing

In Swift 3 I want to create a dictionary that stores classes of a certain type (i.e. the class of a type, not instances) and also use the class type as the key ...

```
var viewDelegates = [MyViewDelegate.Type : MyViewDelegate.Type]()
```

But this gives me *Type MyViewDelegate.Type does not conform to protocol Hashable*. If I use `MyViewDelegate.self` instead of `MyViewDelegate.Type` I get another error: *Type of expression is ambiguous without more context*.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I think `enum` is better solution for this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?